# Ionic IOS project using SocketJS and Stomp Error : Whoops! Lost connection to 'URL'

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, stomp, rsocket-js

I don't know why my Ionic socketjs service can run successfully in a browser but can not build connection when running as a IOS vm in Xcode.

Here's my socketjs service code. Can someone please help me with this, Thanks.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StompService {
    private connecting: boolean = false;
    private topicQueue: any[] = [];

    options = {
        timeout: 10000, // 设置超时时间为 10 秒
      };
    socket = new SockJS('http://44.211.141.255:8080/sba-websocket',undefined,this.options);
    stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
    
    subscribe(topic: string, callback?: any): void {
        // If stomp client is currently connecting add the topic to the queue
        if (this.connecting) {
            console.log("ing");
            this.topicQueue.push({
                topic,
                callback
            });
            return;
        }
        console.log("2");
        const connected: boolean = this.stompClient.connected;
        if (connected) {
            // Once we are connected set connecting flag to false
            console.log("ed");
            this.connecting = false;
            this.subscribeToTopic(topic, callback);
            return;
        }

        // If stomp client is not connected connect and subscribe to topic
        this.connecting = true;
        this.stompClient.connect({}, (): any => {
            this.subscribeToTopic(topic, callback);

            // Once we are connected loop the queue and subscribe to remaining topics from it
            this.topicQueue.forEach((item:any) => {
                this.subscribeToTopic(item.topic, item.callback);
            })

            // Once done empty the queue
            this.topicQueue = [];
        });
    }

    private subscribeToTopic(topic: string, callback?: any): void {
        this.stompClient.subscribe(topic, (response?:string): any => {
            console.log(response);
            callback(response);
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the error message

```
[log] - Opening Web Socket...
[log] - Whoops! Lost connection to http://44.211.141.255:8080/sba-websocket
```

Help me fix the issue please